# Flink is not able to serialize scala classes / Task Not Serializable

Tags: scala, serialization, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have scala class having 2 fields which are **vals** but flink is saying it doesn't have setters. Thus task is not serializable.

I tried setters using var but then it says duplicate setter. vals are public then why it is asking for setters. Flink version 1.1.0

```
class Impression(val map: Map[String, String],val keySet:Set[String])
```

My code:

```
  val preAggregate = stream
.filter(impression => {
    true
})
 .map(impression => {
  val xmap = impression.map
  val values = valFunction(xmap)
  new ImpressionRecord(impression, values._1, values._2, values._3)
})
```

Exceptions:

```
**class Impression does not contain a setter for field map**
19:54:49.995 [main] INFO  o.a.f.a.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor - class Impression is not a valid POJO type
19:54:49.997 [main] DEBUG o.a.flink.api.scala.ClosureCleaner$ - accessedFields: Map(class  -> Set())
Exception in thread "main" **org.apache.flink.api.common.InvalidProgramException: Task not serializable
at** org.apache.flink.api.scala.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:172)
at )
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.DataStream
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1183)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.serializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:301)
at org.apache.flink.api.scala.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:170)
... 18 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use fields of classes directly rather wrap it inside a method and you are almost good to go.